# App rejected, Health app permissions

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchkit, healthkit

I'm having trouble getting my app approved, and to be honest, I'm having trouble understanding what Apple are on about in this case.

My app only uses HealthKit to create, pause, and finish a workout. It does not read any data.

From Apple:
"Regarding the 2.1 issue, your app displays a window on iOS shortly after launching the watch app to start the process to allow your app to integrate with the Health app. No action takes place after tapping on “Open [AppName].” It would be appropriate to ensure your app displays the Health UI to allow permission to access the Health app."

The problem appears to be with my watchOS app not asking for permission to use the Health app. This is the code I'm using to do so:

In my `ExtensionDelegate`:

```
WorkoutManager.sharedManager.requestAuthorisation()
```

The `requestAuthorisation` function in my `WorkoutManager`:

```
//request workout authorisation only
func requestAuthorisation() {
    let writeTypes: Set<HKSampleType> = Set([ HKObjectType.workoutType() ]) //to write a workout

    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: writeTypes, read: nil) { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.debug.log(tag: "WorkoutManager", content: "Error requesting HealthStore authorisation: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my iOS app does not use HealthKit (at least at the moment), so I'm not doing anything with HealthKit in the iOS app. Only the watchOS app uses HealthKit.

When you first run the app on the watch, it prompts you to allow authorisation to access the Health app. An accept or deny pop up appears on the iPhone, where you can choose. I thought this is what they were wanting? Surely they don't want me to custom write some "do you want to allow access to the Health app" view controller?

Answer (score -2):

Apple are very strict about their apps, so you will need to have as many details as you can , when the pop up opens it needs to ask the user explicitly if they want to allow it to communicate with the health app

Comment: I'm already doing this? I don't have any control over the little pop up that appears...

Comment: from what i understood , they want you to open the health app after then going back to your app , like when you connect via facebook and a facebook page opens up then closes and takes you back to your app